# How to set authorization to queryESFunction in Amazon ElasticSearch while deploying the application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am building a searchable enterprise document repository using this blog as a reference: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/creating-a-searchable-enterprise-document-repository/

Creating the Amazon ElasticSearch domain was a success.
I have created an S3 bucket as well.
I am using this repo (as specified in the blog): https://github.com/aws-samples/s3-to-lambda-patterns/tree/master/docrepository
But, deploying the application doesn't work.

I updated the 'samconfig.toml' file with the right bucket name and ESdomain.

The command 'sam deploy' results in a failure.
Error: queryESFunction may not have authorization defined.
[image]
What changes should I make to make this work?

I think we may have to set some authorization in 'template.yaml' file, but what property should I set there?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the application configures an API Gateway, API without authorization.

Here are a few options (not tested):

1. Define Lambda request authorizers as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-controlling-access-to-apis.html).
2. Try to disable auth inside your template.yaml (api resource):

   ```
   Resources:
     MyApi:
       Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
       Properties:
         StageName: Dev
         Auth:
           Authorizer: 'NONE'
   ```
3. Run command `sam deploy --guided`. Follow the on-screen prompts till you see queryESFunction may not have authorization defined prompt.

> For the prompt HelloWorldFunction may not have authorization defined,
> Is this okay? [y/N] AWS SAM is informing you that the sample
> application configures an API Gateway API without authorization. When
> you deploy the sample application, AWS SAM creates a publicly
> available URL.
>
> You can acknowledge this notification by answering "Y" to the prompt.
> For information configuring authorization, see Controlling access to
> API Gateway APIs.

From [Deploy your application to the AWS Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html)

Comment: @Sathyapriyan C any luck with that?

Comment: It didn't work.
Using point 2, I updated my template.yaml file, but I got the same error.
Using point 3, I again got the same error.
Point 1 seems a bit complex. I read the guide in the link, but couldn't understand it clearly.